# creating a stream that passes data through a child process with streams2

Tags: node.js

suppose I have a function `BlackBox`. the api is something like this (where `|` are, in fact, pipes):

```
inputStream | BlackBox | outputStream
```

However, `BlackBox` is actually a wrapper for a `require('child_process').spawn`, so really it looks like this:

```
inputStream | BlackBox.Writable -> proc.stdin -> proc.stdout -> BlackBox.Readable | outputStream
```

I can easily do this with `streams1`, but I want to understand `streams2` and how it is better. Thus, I have the following code so far:

```
var Duplex = require('stream').Duplex
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var util = require('util')

util.inherits(BlackBox, Duplex)

function BlackBox () {
  Duplex.call(this)

  // Example process
  this.proc = spawn('convert', ['-', ':-'])

  var that = this
  this.proc.stdout.on('end', function () {
    that.push(null)
  })
}

BlackBox.prototype._write = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {
  return this.proc.stdin.write(chunk, encoding, callback)
}

BlackBox.prototype.end = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {
  return this.proc.stdin.end(chunk, encoding, callback)
}

BlackBox.prototype._read = function (size) {
  var that = this

  this.proc.stdout.on('readable', function () {
    var chunk = this.read(size)
    if (chunk === null)
      that.push('')
    else
      that.push(chunk)
  })
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

My main concern is the following excerpt from the documentation on `readable._read(size)`:

> When data is available, put it into the read queue by calling readable.push(chunk). If push returns false, then you should stop reading. When _read is called again, you should start pushing more data.

how do i "stop reading"?

To be clear, I want back pressure and throttling to be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isaacs basically made an example: https://github.com/isaacs/duplex-passthrough